# How to flash my ESP8266 back, having already written to it?

Tags: lua, infinite-loop, esp8266

I'm a ESP8266 beginner, and I have a ESP8266 devkit. I flash it with [esptools](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) and use [ESPlorer](https://esp8266.ru/esplorer/) as IDE.

I classically made the infinite loop error, but I manage to get out of it by erasing flash (`erase_flash` command from esptools) on whole flash memory (including user space).

To avoid this again, I made the following code

`init.lua`

```
dofile('crazy-guard.lua')
```

`crazy-guard.lua`

```
gpio.mode(0,gpio.INPUT)
programPinValue = gpio.read(0)

if(programPinValue == 0) then
    print("program mode")
    return
else then
    print("run mode")
    dofile('program.lua')
end
```

`program.lua`

```
while true do

end
```

This is working as expected : if I low GPIO0, I get "program mode" written on ESPlorer console when I establish connection. If set hig, I get the "run mode" message.

**I thought that the `return` instruction on program mode block (GPIO0 low) would allow me to communicate with my ESP8266 dev kit (editing .lua files)** but since I uploaded this code, I can't get any connection on my board... esptools return :

```
sudo python ./esptool.py erase_flash
```

> esptool.py v2.4.1
>
> Found 1 serial ports Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
>   Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
>   /dev/ttyUSB0 failed to connect: Failed to connect to Espressif device:
>   Timed out waiting for packet header

One the ESPlorer side, here is what I get :

> PORT OPEN 115200
>
> Communication with MCU..Got answer! Communication with MCU
>   established. AutoDetect firmware...
>
> Can't autodetect firmware, because proper answer not received (may be
>   unknown firmware).  Please, reset module or continue.
>   l�d����#�n�l�#|���2�{���b��no�lNn���cp��$rdrlp�n��dbN�|��䎟�c��oN�d���$`�no�s$or���Nrld
>   p�n�r�����bN��o�l�p��on���l �oN�ln{���o�l
>   p�N�r�����bN�|l섎p��on���l
>   �no�{lNs�����{${��o�{$����n�{��n|�lll$`b��|{�l�n��n��l`��r�l�$�$`��{�l�$�l`��{�l���dl`rl��o��bc��cp|"p���p����lB��N�Nn��ld��l���d��$����$��d
>   �n�����bl$��2b���"l�crlr
>
> NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com    branch: master  commit:
>   5073c199c01d4d7bbbcd0ae1f761ecc4687f7217  SSL: false  modules:
>   file,gpio,http,i2c,mqtt,net,node,ow,tmr,uart,wifi  build  built on:
>   2018-03-22 17:00  powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 2.1.0(116b762)
>
> program mode

Then if I try any command over USB via ESPlorer, or pushing any file edit/creation, I get :

> Waiting answer from ESP - Timeout reached. Command aborted.

As far as I can see, my devkit seems bricked. How can I reprogram it? I tried  to change bauds, but the NodeMCU header with firmware details makes me think that hardware communication is correctly set.

Comment: Can't give a definite answer as it's all a bit convoluted. You're on Unix, right? `/dev/ttyUSB0 ` is the correct port? It'd odd that `esptool.py` would fail to connect but connection with ESPlorer can be established. You can safely ignore the "Can't autodetect firmware, because yadayada" message. The boot message from my cloud builder ("NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com") tells a different story. However, once you flash the NodeMCU firmware you don't have the AT firmware installed anymore i.e. it's to be expected that AT commands fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I&#39;m on UNIX-based (Ubuntu) and my mistake for AT command. I meant commands sent through USB via ESPlorer. Would you have an idea about recovery?

Comment: You may force the GPIOs in corresponding to signal levels from [ESP Boot Process](https://github.com/esp8266/esp8266-wiki/wiki/Boot-Process) with e.g. 10k resistors to the +3.3V or GND.